# When can IEnumerable not be converted to IList?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I found this code in a project I'm working on:

```
IEnumerable<int> foo = iEnumerableIntVariable as IList<int> ?? iEnumerableIntVariable.ToList();
```

I know that [`as` returns null if it can't successfully convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx), and that `ToList()` would then kick in to finish the job, but what are the situations in which that would happen?

Comment: I assume u mean IList<int> foo = .....

Comment: @pm100 No, all I did was change the variable names. The code is otherwise exactly as it appears.

Comment: Erm...What about if it is a database query `IQueryable<int>`. What about if it is `Set<int>`, what if it is a method that `yield`s ints.

Comment: If it's a type that implements `IEnumerable` but not `IList`.

Comment: What are all of the situations where you'll have an animal that isn't a cat?  What are all of the situations where you have a planet that isn't Earth?  What are all of the situations where you have code that isn't written in C#?

Comment: i wonder what the code is for then. since you could just go IEnumerable<int> foo = IEnumeravleIntVariable.

Comment: all fish live in the sea, not all things in the sea are fish

Comment: @pm100 So then what are the things in my aquarium, if they're not fish (since my aquarium isn't the sea).

Comment: @Servy Of course your aquarium is the sea. All fish live in the sea. Fish live in your aquarium. Therefore your aquarium is the sea. That's just basic logic.

Comment: @octothorpentine or they are dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among others, consider this simple case:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetListOfNumbers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        yield return i;
}
```

This returns a true `IEnumerable` that wouldn't implement `IList` as well ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)). Clearly, adding/removing from this "collection" doesn't make any sense, nor are elements accessible via index.

Comment: Not only that. `IList` must be accessible by index.